# How can youtube increase my video bitrate?

Tags: youtube, bitrate

So basically I have exported a video with an avg of 2000kbps bitrate. File size was around 60mb or so. Once uploaded to youtube, I try to download it from my videos youtube tab and when I check the downloaded video's bitrate, it has an average of 3000kbps bitrate and a video size of 110mb. How is that possible? Exported video had a max of 2000kbps bixrate set up.

Comment: Youtube re-encodes all video uploads. I can't find a source offhand, otherwise I'd post this as an answer. But that's almost certainly what's happening.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but I never came accross of youtube increasing the bitrate, only decreasing it.